# This doesn't seem to work. No error message or anything, "time" just doesn't print. now and decisecond both show the right values.

Tags: python

Everything up here is fine

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    now = str(datetime.now())
    decisecond = now[20]
```

This part doesn't work

```
    if decisecond == 1:
        print(time)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please edit the subject line to describe the problem.  "This doesn't work" would apply to most of the questions posted here!  Try something like "How to print time in python."

Answer (score 2):

It's because 'decisecond' isn't an int. Change the if statement to this, and it will work:

```
if int(decisecond) == 1:
        print(time)
```

In saying that, printing 'time' will not print what I think you want it to. Probably change it to print the datetime, so the whole code is:
from datetime import datetime

```
while True:
    now = str(datetime.now())
    decisecond = now[20]
    if int(decisecond) == 1:
        print(datetime.now())
```